# Talk to a non-detected nfc tag

Tags: android, nfc, rfid

I'm trying to interact with an NFC tag which is not detected by my android phone (Nexus 5). No intent is received when the tag gets closer to the phone.

The tag is a SRIX4K EEPROM, according to the datasheet this chip works at 13.56 MHz and follows the ISO 14443-2 Type B standard, so in my application code I used the NfcB tech object but since the tag isn't detected by the system the app doesn't even reach the point in which NfcB object is used.

I can talk to the tag with no problem using libnfc and a PN532 reader from a linux application, so I know the tag is working and the ISO 14443-2 Type B is the right standard to use.
The app detects other tags just fine and can distinguish between NfcB tags and other tags.

I think the way android detects new tags is not supported by or not working correctly with this chip. Is there any way to do one of the following things?

- force the android system to talk to the tag without any intent
- trick the android system to think a tag is present and then see what
  happens with the NfcB transceive method

I'm open to others ideas too. The phone is rooted and since this is for personal use I can modify the system if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with this application if tag is detected:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.mroland.android.apps.nfctaginfo

- If yes, have a look to "Tag information" to known how Android see this tag.
- If no, it seems NFC Chip embedded in this phone not support this kind of tag.

Comment: Thanks that's one of the apps I've already tried and it doesn't detect the tag. The point is that I can use the tag with ISO 14443 B standard with a PN532 reader, and that the phone can detect other tags with B standard just not this SRIX. I think I need to take a look at how Android system detects a new tag at a lower level.. Do you know which part of the OS takes care of that? Thanks